# C# Passing string between forms

Tags: c#, winforms

newbie question
Passing veriable between two forms, it's a string "LoggedUserName"

I have MainForm that starts LoggingFrm:

```
    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        LoggingFrm newLogin = new LoggingFrm();
        
        newLogin.ShowDialog();

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(newLogin.LoggedUser))
        {
            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            User = newLogin.LoggedUser;
            tsslUser.Text = Uzytkownik;
            LoggedUser = User;
            
        }
    }
```

And logging frm:

```
    private string User;
    public string LoggedUser 
    { 
        get
        {
            return User;
        }
        set
        {
            User = value;
        }
    }

    private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        String user = tbUser.Text;
        String pass = tbPassword.Text;
        if (IsLogin(user, pass))                  // Mysql code behind
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Logged as {user}!");
            LoggedUser = tbUser.Text;            //Setting public string
            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"User {user} not found!");
        }

    }
```

and third form with

```
LoggingFrm frm = new LoggingFrm();

lblTest.Text = frm.LoggedUser
```

And at that point it works fine, but if I try to transfer the string to any different form it doesn't work - string is null.

no matter if I try to pass it from LoggingFrm or MainFrm

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: A common solution for inter-form communication is to keep references between them. Often opening a new form with a parameter is a simple solution: `LoggingFrm newLogin = new LoggingFrm(this);`. This passes the main form to the child form. There, in the constructor, you should copy that refence to a class level variable.. This is similar to the post below, but of course much more porwerful and dynamic - Now you can access all (public or internal) fiields or properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use your `LoggingFrm.LoggedUser` prop to always return the once-set value then make the appropriate member field `static`:

```
private static string User;
```

Every classes instantiating a `LoggingFrm` can reach the value through `LoggedUser` property now at least if it was once set.

ps: forms are `IDisposable`, use them in using block!

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing `LoggedUser` to the third form in that example. You're creating a new instance of `LoggingFrm` in the third form. This is a completely different object than the one you created in the `Form1_Load` method - none of the non-static members are going to "carry over" between instances. Unless you're manually setting something in the constructor for `LoggingFrm`, then everything is going to be the default value when you create that new instance in your third form. This is why the `string` is `null`.

In order to pass the `LoggedUser` value that was entered in `LoggingFrm` around, one option is to store that value in `Form1`. You're already doing that inside of the `else` block in the properties or fields `User` and `LoggedUser`. Then when you create the instance of the third form, you need to pass the values you stored in `Form1` to the third form's constructor.

```
public class ThirdForm
{
    public ThirdForm(string loggedUser)
    {
        LoggedUser = loggedUser;
    }
    
    private string LoggedUser { get; set; }
}

public class Form1
{
    private launchThirdFrmBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThirdForm frm = new ThirdForm(User);
        frm.Show();
    }
}
```